# Using a Regex to match all emotes, not just the first match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to match emotes and replace the emote characters with an image. I have the following:

```
var emotes ={
    "laughing": Array(":))"),
    "smile": Array(":o)",":-)",":)","=]","=)"),
    "sick": Array(":-&")
};
```

Then I find the matches using:

```
function emoticons(html){
    for(var emoticon in emotes){
        for(var i = 0; i < emotes[emoticon].length; i++){
            // Replace the emote with the image
            html = html.replace(emotes[emoticon][i],"<img src=\""+icon_folder+"/face-"+emoticon+".png\" class=\"emoticonimg\" />","g");
        }
    }
    return html;
}
return this.each(function(){
    $(this).html(emoticons($(this).html()));
});
```

The issues are:

1. If the html equals ":) :) :) :) :)" It is only replacing the first instance, not all
2. Laughing, :)), it being picked up as a smile with a trailing )
3. sick ends up outputting amp; html? "`<img src="/images/emoticons/face-sick.png" class="emoticonimg">amp;`" at the end

Any RegEx experts able to lend a hand? Thanks

Comment: As to issue 3), it's because the 'sick' emoticon looks like `:-&amp;` in the HTML source, so the `:-&` is replaced with the `<img ...>` but the `amp;` remains. If you change your `emotes['sick']` to `:-&amp;` it'll be fine.

Comment: Also, you don't need regex here as you're just trying to match literal, fixed, known strings -- otherwise you'll have to go escape all the brackets which is unnecessary. (by the way, when I run your code it replaces all instances for me...)

Comment: Could you jsfiddle a minimal working example that reproduces your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9D7Bk/ it shows how it's only matching one time... for issue #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see the issue -- to do multiple replaces you have to use regex and add the `g` (global) modifier at the end, which does the multiple replaces.

In that case you'll have to "regex-safe" your emoticons, which for you is basically escaping brackets with backslash, and escaping the backslash to get around javascript interpreting them.

To deal with issue 3 we replace the `:-&` with `:-&amp;` which is how it appears in HTML.

```
var emotes ={
    "laughing": Array(":\\)\\)"),
    "smile": Array(":o\\)",":-\\)",":\\)","=\\]","=\\)"),
    "sick": Array(":-&amp;")
};
```

Then to make the regex:

```
var re = new RegExp(emotes[emoticon][i],"g"); // <-- replace all occurences
html = html.replace(re,"<img src=\""...);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9D7Bk/7/

You'll just have to be careful about:

- escaping `[]()!.*+{}?^$` in emoticons
- converting `&` -> `&amp;`, `>` to `&gt;` etc in your `emotes`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery.fn.emoticons = function (icon_folder) {
    /* emoticons is the folder where the emoticons are stored*/
    var icon_folder = icon_folder || "http://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~skreft/emoticon/emoticons";
    //var settings = jQuery.extend({emoticons: "emoticons"}, options);
    /* keys are the emoticons
    * values are the ways of writing the emoticon
    *
    * for each emoticons should be an image with filename
    * 'face-emoticon.png'
    * so for example, if we want to add a cow emoticon
    * we add "cow" : Array("(C)") to emotes
    * and an image called 'face-cow.png' under the emoticons folder   
    */
    var emotes = {
        "laughing": Array(":))"),
        "smile": Array(":o)", ":-)", ":)", "=]", "=)"),
        "sick": Array(":-&")
    };

    function emoticonsReplace(str) {
        var ret = str.replace(/\&amp;/g, "&").replace(/\:\)\)|\:\o\)|\:\-\)|\:\)|\=\]|\=\)|\:\-\&/g, function (match) {
            switch (match) {
                case ":))":
                    return '<img src="' + icon_folder + '/face-laughing.png" class="emoticonimg" />';
                    break;
                case ":o)":
                case ":-)":
                case ":)":
                case "=]":
                case "=)":
                    return '<img src="' + icon_folder + '/face-smile.png" class="emoticonimg" />';
                    break;
                case ":-&":
                    return '<img src="' + icon_folder + '/face-sick.png" class="emoticonimg" />';
                    break;
            }
        });

        return ret;
    }

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html(emoticonsReplace(decodeURIComponent($this.html())));
    });
};
```

---

I've edited this to be a complete solution.  It works for me :)

---

I redited it to be used in your jsFiddle.  When I ran, it worked.

Comment: the `/g` refers to the fact that it does a global search (so it continues past the first instance).

Comment: just replace the words "laughing", ... with whatever `<img />` you need

Comment: That seems pretty messy. I like the way it's structured now, it's more flexible and scalable.  Wonder why it's only doing it once on my end?

Comment: really?  this code I ran with more than 5 emoticons and it worked perfectly for me...please send me your test code, or a small snippet of the html you're sending it :) ...

Comment: I believe that to do multi-replace you need to use regular expressions.  On the upside, this methodology only parses the html string once, while the for loop will parse the html as many times as the number of emoticons types there are.